# AMP : Can't load Shadow AMP script

Tags: amp-html

When loading this script tag (`<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/shadow-v0.js"></script>`), I have an error which said "unknown script".

[Shadow AMP script Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf7tv.png)

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Now, even though I don't touch anything, Error is gone.

I think it is not my fault but some network condition ? or amp projects error.

:d